# Blinking element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make an HTML blinking, I did the code below but it doesn't work correctly. At the beginning the element is visible but after 1000ms it disappears and I have to refresh the page to see it again. As far as I'm concerned this code should work so the issue should be with the sequence of calling a function by browser.

```js
function blink() {
  //pick an element from HTML //
  var titleOfGame = document.querySelector('#game-title');

  //check if the title is hidden or visible
  if (titleOfGame.style.visibility === 'hidden') { // [editor: was 'hidded']
    titleOfGame.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    titleOfGame.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
//set interval to the blink function//
window.setInterval(blink, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="game-title">World of Warcraft</div>
```

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo: `hidded` isn't how you spell `hidden`

Comment: You misspelled ``hidden`` in your if statement. That's the problem.

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed the hidded typo

Comment: In my opinion, these questions should not be edited to fix the typo, because it makes the question pointless.

Comment: @TamasSzoke Normally the question should be deleted, but because there now is a much cooler answer, it could stay with the comment. It i already closed as typo-type so not really difficult to figure out

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to do it using CSS:

```css
.game-title{
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="game-title">Game Title</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a little typo

```
titleOfGame.style.visibility === 'hidded' 
// should be 
titleOfGame.style.visibility === 'hidden'
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo type questions